# How to fetch the information after Google`s New policy on permission of SMS, Call Log?

Tags: android, permissions, sms, call

"**Apps must be actively registered as the default SMS, Phone, or Assistant handler before prompting users to accept any of the above permissions and must immediately stop the use of the permission when it's no longer the default handler**." in the [Google Doc](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/).

In the same doc "**It must be actively registered as the default Phone or Assistant handler on the device.**"

Does it mean that at any time **only and only one** app is allowed to fetch the Call Logs or SMS information?

- If Yes then how to get the Call Log and SMS information?
- If No Then how this new Policy impacted my app which works only on
  Call Log and SMS?

  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Does it mean that at any time only and only one app is allowed to fetch the Call Logs or SMS information?" -- that is how I interpreted their new rule, though it is not completely clear. However, please note that this is a Play Store rule, not an OS rule. [Stack Overflow is not a good place to get help with the rules imposed by app distribution channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: @CommonsWare... As the Doc, we have to update app within 90 days according to policy. It's not clear to me what has to change. If you find any clear definition plz share.

Comment: Please answer if you find a one or the way to get logs. As there can be really a need to someone like me (without malicious purpose).

Comment: Is it good to go with device admin feature for this as solution?

Comment: @mnp343.. I m still searching the valid solution.

Comment: Has anyone else filled out the exemption form? I received no confirmation email from Google after successfully submitting it. Also, the developer console still says my app will be removed on Jan 9th though the exemption application stated that I would receive 2 additional months. I know that once Google removes your app it is permanent unless it was deemed to be a mistake. The whole process is a little unpleasant and a little unclear.

Comment: I just got done chatting with GooglePlay tech support. They refused to send me a confirmation of the 2 month extension. So i have a choice between living in fear or removing the app.